# Sorry, I was in the Gym

Tags: word-choice

In the sentence `Sorry, I was in the Gym`, should I use `in`, `on` or `at`? Is there a rule of thumb that I can follow to always know which one to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "I was at the gym" sounds more natural and is probably more common. But it could depend on the situation.

The general rule of thumb is that for larger locations (think city, country, continent) you'd probably use **in**. "I was **at** Chicago" sounds odd, but "I was **in** Chicago" sounds normal. "I was **in** Africa last summer" instead of "I was **at** Africa". For smaller locations, you could use **at**. Examples "I was **at** the grocery store", "I saw him **at** the movies", etc. In this case, **at** can refer to inside of a particular building or just outside of it. "I parked **at** the mall". Everyone would understand this to mean that you parked in an area just outside of the mall building itself and not inside of the mall building.

One exception, is if you want to emphasize that something took place inside of a location as opposed to outside.

Ex 1: "When I was **in** the gym, it started raining" This explicitly tells the listener that you were inside of the building itself and not outside.

Ex 2: If you and friend A are standing outside of the gym and friend B is inside of the gym, you wouldn't say, "B is **at** the gym", because you're all at the gym. You would say "B is **in** the gym" to explicitly state that he's inside of the building as opposed to outside of it.

Ex 3: If you're in a larger building that contains another location. If you and friend A are inside of the mall and friend B is inside the movie theater, which is also inside of the mall, you might say "B is **in** the movie theater" If B were inside of the mall, but outside of the movie theater, then you'd probably say "B is **at** the movie theater"

Some more examples, explanations, and exceptions: 
https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2013/05/14/english-preposition-lesson-at-vs-in-for-location/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we use **at**, **in** and **on** when we talk about the location of things.

What do the prepostions in these three things tell us about the locations?

> "Meet Simon at the end of the road."
>
> "You left your glasses in the bathroom."
>
> "Is that a spider on the wall?"

**At** a Point
**At** tells us that the following noun is located at a specific point or location. It shows an exact position.

> "She's waiting at the entrance."
>
> "He's sitting on his chair at his desk."
>
> "I work at a bank."

**In** an Enclosed Space
**In** tells us the noun is in an enclosed space (surround or closed off on all sides). Basically, when something is inside something.

> In a box. In a room. In a country.

**On** a Surface
**On** tells us that the following noun is located on a surface. Use on when one thing is attatched to or touching somthing.

> On the table. On the floor. On the chair.

**What's the difference bewteen these two sentences?**

> She's at the library.
>
> She's in the library.

She's **at** the library. - **the emphasis is on her location and the type of place she has gone to.**
She's **in** the library. - **the emphasis is on the type of place she is inside.**

Both of these sentences are fine to answer the question, **"Where is she?"**